# @Media style not being applied for iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to apply @media style to an iFrame, but it is not working properly.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        @media (max-width:1199px) {
            .myiframe {
                width: 1100px;
            }
        }

        /* Style for Large Screen */
        @media (max-width:991px) {
            .myiframe {
                width: 900px;
            }
        }

        /* Style for Medium Screen */
        @media (max-width:767px) {
            .myiframe {
                width: 600px;
            }
        }

        /* Style for Small Screen */
        @media (max-width:575px) {
            .myiframe {
                width: 550px;
            }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe class="myiframe" src="./test.html" style="height: 1000px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Doesn't matter the width of the browser it always open in the same default width size. Can't I use @media for iFrames?

Thanks

Comment: Works in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o742v6Lc/2/ on Chrome Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: It's not working on Firefox

Comment: The inline HTML `style` attribute takes precedence over CSS.

Comment: Here's your styling precedence order from greatest to least: JavaScript `Element.style`, HTML Element `style` attribute, HTML `<link />` tag for CSS, HTML `<style></style>` tag for CSS.

Comment: Yes. I'm using inline ```<style>``` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make it responsive by wrapping your iframe in a div and applying the @media code to the parent div element.  An example can be found [here](https://davidwalsh.name/responsive-iframes)